# How can I customize the title/subtitle font in callout from MKAnnotationView or just hide them?

Tags: swift, mapkit, title, mkannotation, callout

I have a view to a calloutDetail:
    `annotationView.detailCalloutAccessoryView = mapInformationView.view`

It is working just fine, but I don't want to display a title/subtitle, just my custom view. But when I left title/subtitle empty the callout isn't displayed.

So, How can I hide them or just change their font size and name?

Comment: Hello, Did you find a solution to that problem ?

Comment: Yes, I have found. I will post it as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

One way to hide the title (or subtitle) label is to set the `MKAnnotation`'s `title` (or `subtitle`) property to `nil`.

If you want the title to show on the marker, but not on the callout, toggle the `title` value in a subclass of `MKAnnotationView` overriding `setSelected(_:animated:)`.

```
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    if selected {
        annotation.title = nil
    } else {
        annotation.title = "Title"
    }
    
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
}
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to work - the compiler complains that `annotation.title` is a get-only property.

Comment: setting the annotation's title empty in `mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotation) ` mostly works, but produces an annoying animation to get rid of the blank space left behind.